# The application encountered an error while attempting to change the state of Virtual Machine over windows server 2008 R2 sp1 host

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I had to shut down my VM on the Hyper V host and when i tried to start it again. i started to have this Error `Application error when you attempt to change the status of Svv-Log01`

Did anyone face this issue or how can

Comment: Are there any corresponding events in the Application or System event logs?

Comment: i didn't find any , do you know where should i look for

Comment: `
The description for Event ID "12140" from the source "Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker" was not found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on the local computer, or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.`

Answer (score 1):

The event ID 12140 means that Hyper-V can't claim the resources that the VM is configured to use. Some things to check:

- "Eject" any CD's, or if the CD drive is attached to your physical CD drive then switch it to "None".
- Make sure the VHD file is not attached to another VM or mounted on the host in Disk Management.
- If the VM has a saved state, try deleting the saved state and starting the VM cold.
- Make sure the v-switch the NIC's are connected to still exists.

Comment: This VHD is not connected to any other VM  and i didn't get your other Points.  can you please help me With it.
thanks @longneck

Comment: I have  checked it now again the VHD is alos not mounted in Disk Managment